# ANE-Facebook, [application] has stopped, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity

Tags: java, facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, ane

I'm new to ANE-Facebook, however I've got positive experience with some other Freshplanet's ANEs.
The subject **question is**: Is my configuration wrong or is the issue caused by ANE's code?

This AIR app stops right after calling `openSessionWithReadPermissions`
For obvious reasons, the text bellow and attached [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Z-tgto3OaicDJzaUNmd1k1TGs/view?usp=sharing) have values replaced as follows:
*MyNumericAppId* - my app id ('0234XXXXXXXXX')
*air.com.mydomain.myapp.debug* - my app package (air.com.recxxxxx.xxxxx.debug)

1. I've configured manifest and extension sections in application.xml according to freshplanet's readme and howto:

   `<application>
       <id>com.mydomain.myapp</id> <!-- debug is being added automatically -->
   [...]
       <android>
           <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
               <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
   [...]
                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                    <application>
                       <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"/>
                       <activity android:name="com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"></activity>
                       <activity android:name="com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.ShareDialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"></activity>
                       <activity android:name="com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.ShareOGActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"></activity>
                       <activity android:name="com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.WebDialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"></activity>

                  </application>
               </manifest> 
           ]]></manifestAdditions>
       </android>
   [...]
       <extensions>
               <extensionID>com.freshplanet.AirFacebook</extensionID>
       </extensions>
   </application>`
2. I've configured app facebook side (generated hashes based on certificate and password I've created earlier).
   [image: facebook.config]
3. I call methods in order:

   `trace("Facebook.isSupported", Facebook.isSupported);
   Facebook.getInstance().init(MyNumericAppId,false);
   Facebook.getInstance().logEnabled = true;
   trace("Facebook.getInstance().isSessionOpen" Facebook.getInstance().isSessionOpen);
   Facebook.getInstance().closeSessionAndClearTokenInformation();
   Facebook.getInstance().openSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "user_friends"],aneSessionResult);`

**The Issue:** Method `aneSessionResult` is never executed. Application stops immediately after calling `openSessionWithReadPermissions` and exits on confirmation. No ActionScript level error is being thrown. Delaying or triggering this method on user's input event - gives the very same result.

I'm attaching full info-level, not filtered [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Z-tgto3OaicDJzaUNmd1k1TGs/view?usp=sharing), captured from start of the app till the crash occurrence (replaced app id and package).

Once again: Is my configuration wrong or is it something to do with ANE itself?
Thank you

P.S. either me or SO can't handle code formatting for this post. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Watched your log, there is a line

```
03-13 00:01:00.260: I/dalvikvm(6428): Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance, referenced from method com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.flushAndWait
```

That means class android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager is missing from ANE. I unzipped ANE from github and did not find either android-support-v4.jar or the class itself.

You can rebuild ANE on your own, you only need to add android-support-v4.jar to package dependencies in build/platform-android.xml.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to set-up all the sdks and environmental things before I go with your solution. This may take a while. Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. I've successfully added android-support-v4.jar to the package (needed to edit build.xml too). This info is not thrown anymore but app gets terminated exactly the same way. Updated [log file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Z-tgto3OaiMnFZcGVRSzZ6UHM/view?usp=sharing) Thanks